# hotkey/hotstring to print last variable/all defined variables in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

In Intellij for java I can type  `soutv +` <kbd>tab</kbd> and it will expand it to
`System.out.println("var1 = " var1 ", var2, "  = ", var 2)`

etc.

Is there someting equivalent in PyCharm for python?

A hotstring that I type so it automatically creates something like
`print("var1=", var1, ...)` 
?

(in IntelliJ for java there is also sout, soutm, soutp etc..  again: equivalent in PyCharm for python?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is live templates.

I believe, the difference is that all python is runtime, so you can't really build namespace/scope while writing the code. What you can do, tho, is to create live template like this:

```
print([f'{name} = {value}' for name, value in locals().items()])
```

[image]

Now you can use `plocals` + <kbd>tab</kbd> to insert line of code that will print out all variables in local scope

Note: formatting is for py 3.6+, but that's just for illustrative purposes